# How to get the next pages using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing code to extract all products from given urls It works fine but some urls contain many pages so I'm trying to get all the next pages by find the ul that holds the pages urls the problem is it display only the first 3 pages and the last page 
[image]
Pagination ul

```
    <li class="plp-pagination__nav disable">
           <a href="" rel="prev" class="plp-pagination__navpre">
             previous </a>
         </li>
    <li class="plp-pagination__nav active"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a></li>
            <li class="plp-pagination__nav"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="here is the page url ">2</a></li>
                <li class="plp-pagination__nav"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="here is the page url">3</a></li>
                <li class="plp-pagination__nav"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="here is the page url">4</a></li>
                <li class="plp-pagination__nav"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="here is the page url">5</a></li>
                <li class="plp-pagination__nav"> <span class="plp-pagination__navplaceholder"></span></li>
             <li class="plp-pagination__nav"><a class="plp-pagination__navpages" href="here is the page url">54</a></li>
       <li class="plp-pagination__nav">
            <a class="plp-pagination__navnext" href="here is the page url" rel="next">
                  next</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Read Function

```
def update():
    df = pd.DataFrame( columns=['poduct_name','image_url','price'])
    #lsit of required pages 
    urls= ['1st page','2nd page','3rd page']

    for url in urls:
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
        #get the list of pages in pagination ul   
        new_pages= soup.find('ul', attrs={'class':'plp-pagination__wrapper'})
        #check if there is pagination ul
        if(new_pages!=None):
            new_urls= new_pages.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'plp-pagination__navpages'})
            for x in new_urls: 
                 urls.append(x)
        product_div= soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__wrap'})
        product_list=[]
        for x in product_div:
            poduct_name= x.find('p', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__name'}).text.strip()
            product_price_p= x.find('p', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__price'}).text
            product_img= x.img['src']
            product_list.append({'poduct_name':poduct_name,'image_url':product_img,'price':product_price})
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(product_list))
    return df
```

Comment: what's the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass this problem by adding the following script:

```
urls= []
home_page = requests.get("https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/food-beverages/c/FKSA1000000?&qsort=relevance&pg")
home_soup = BeautifulSoup(home_page.content, "lxml")
page_nmb_find = home_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"plp-pagination__navpages"})
last_page = int(page_nmb_find[-1].getText())

for nmb in range(0,last_page):
    urls.append(f"https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/food-beverages/c/FKSA1000000?&qsort=relevance&pg={nmb}")
```

All in all your code should look like this:

```
def update():
    df = pd.DataFrame( columns=['poduct_name','image_url','price'])
    #lsit of required pages 
    urls= []
    home_page = requests.get("https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/food-beverages/c/FKSA1000000?&qsort=relevance&pg")
    home_soup = BeautifulSoup(home_page.content, "lxml")
    page_nmb_find = home_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"plp-pagination__navpages"})
    last_page = int(page_nmb_find[-1].getText())
    for nmb in range(0,last_page):
        urls.append(f"https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/food-beverages/c/FKSA1000000?&qsort=relevance&pg={nmb}")

    for url in urls:
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
        #get the list of pages in pagination ul   
        new_pages= soup.find('ul', attrs={'class':'plp-pagination__wrapper'})
        #check if there is pagination ul
        if(new_pages!=None):
            new_urls= new_pages.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'plp-pagination__navpages'})
            for x in new_urls: 
                 urls.append(x)
        product_div= soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__wrap'})
        product_list=[]
        for x in product_div:
            poduct_name= x.find('p', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__name'}).text.strip()
            product_price_p= x.find('p', attrs={'class':'comp-productcard__price'}).text
            product_img= x.img['src']
            product_list.append({'poduct_name':poduct_name,'image_url':product_img,'price':product_price_p})
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(product_list))
    return df
```

*(PS: it appears that `product_price` doesn't exist so I replaced it with `product_price_p`)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: (0,53) what about if the products increased and the number of pages increased ?

Comment: @R_Developer I've just updated the code. The number of products per page shouldn't change anything. Now the code checks how many pages there are and gets them all.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the website in question is [Carrefour](https://www.carrefourksa.com/mafsau/en/food-beverages/c/FKSA1000000?&qsort=relevance).
This is roughly how I would do it (pseudocode).

One would request the first page. After requesting said page, one could get the anchor with class `plp-pagination__navnext`. One would then use this anchor's href as the next URL to request. You don't have a list of all page URLs at the start. After requesting a page, you scrape the next page's URL and request it.

Pseudocode:

```
1. Load first page
2. Scrape whatever you're looking to scrape
3. Get href of next page element via selector 'a.pagination__navnext'
4. Load the next page (its URL is the href you just acquired)
5. Repeat from step 2
Stop when reached last page, AKA when next page elem's href is '' on Carrefour.
```